# Django Error: Reverse for 'like_post' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Full error: Reverse for 'like_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['like/(?P[0-9]+)$', 'home/like/(?P[0-9]+)$']

views.py:

```
def like_post(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    liked = False

    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
        liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home-new'))
```

The above code works if i put form action to the url that calls the view but it refreshes the page when i like  a post so im trying to call the view through javascript instead so i tried this

templates:

```
{% block content %}

{% for item in products %}
        <div class="item_btns_container">
            <div class="like_btn_form_container">
                <form id="like_form">//was action="{% url 'like_post' item.id %}"
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if user in item.likes.all %}
                        <button type="submit" class="liked_post" name="post_id" value="{{ item.id }}"><div class="liked_btn" >Like</div></button>
                    {% else %}
                        <button type="submit" class="like_btn" name="post_id"  value="{{ item.id }}"><div class="liked_btn">Like</div></button>
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
            </div>
            
{% endfor %}

<script>
    $(document).on('submit','#like_form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'like_post' item.id %}',
              <script>
    $(document).on('submit','#like_form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'like_post' item.id %}',
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success:function(){
                alert("liked");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

            success:function(){

            }
        });
    });
</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

i also tried this with a different view

```
def like_post(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    liked = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            liked = False
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
            liked = True

    return render(request, 'new.html')
```

models.py:
class Post(models.Model):
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked_posts', null=True, blank=True)

Comment: At that point in the template (the JavaScript), `item` is *not* defined.

Comment: i have edited to put the script below

Comment: but that does *not* matter. The `{% url ... %}` template tag uses `item.id`, but at that time, there is *no* `item.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point you generate the JavaScript code, `item` is *not* defined, hence the error. It might be better to encode the URL in the button, and then make an AJAX call to that URL:

```
<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    $(document).on('submit','#like_form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr("url"),
            data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken},
            success:function(){
            }
        });
    });
</script>

{% block content %}

{% for item in products %}

<div class="item_btns_container">
    <div class="like_btn_form_container">
        <form id="like_form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if user in item.likes.all %}
                <button type="submit" class="liked_post" url="{% url 'like_post' item.id %}" name="post_id" value="{{ item.id }}"><div class="liked_btn" >Like</div></button>
            {% else %}
                <button type="submit" class="like_btn" url="{% url 'like_post' item.id %}" name="post_id" value="{{ item.id }}"><div class="liked_btn">Like</div></button>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, i don't get the reverse error anymore. But is there any chance you can point out where im wrong with liking the post in the views because it doesnt add a like

Comment: @HumzaDin: can you share how the `Post` model? Can you validate that it makes a POST request to the corresponding view?

Comment: @HumzaDin: are you sure it passes the cross-site-request-forgery check (CSRF): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: i added an alert to the function and that is not being called so i am trying to debug right now

Comment: @HumzaDin: do the buttons have a `submit` type.